# ASP.NET MVC 3 Parse JSon object and display data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class

```
public class ConversionResultModel
    {
        public string ProcessId { get; set; }
        public bool Result { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }         
    }
```

sending it to view using JSon

```
   public ActionResult UploadFile(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> clientUpload)
    {
        string destinationPath = "";
        JsonResult result = null;
        var fileModel = new ConversionResultModel();
        fileModel.ProcessId = "4558-95559-554";
        fileModel.Result = true;
        fileModel.Message = "test.pdf";
        result = Json(new { fileModel }, "text/plain");


        return result;
    }
```

How to parse such JSon object at client side using JS or jQuery and read values?

I have tried to parse JSon object with code below but get Undefined error in alert

```
 var obj = $.parseJSON(e.response);
 alert(e.obj);
```

I receive JSon object like this

```
{"fileModel":{"ProcessId":"4558-95559-554","Result":true,"Message":null,"SourceFile":null,"ConvertedFileName":"test.pdf","ConvertedFileSize":1233444,"DownloadUrl":"http://localhost:2008/download?path=4558-95559-554","DeleteUrl":"http://localhost:2008/download?path=4558-95559-554"}}
```

Comment: I have tried to parse with $.parseJSON(e.response) but it do not work.

Comment: What did it do or not do? Were there any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to parse it. Just [set data type to JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) during ajax request and then use received data object like entity and you easily can access to any property:

```
var id = data.ProcessId;
```

Anyway, using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) you can parse JSON string:

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(stringData);
```

P.S:

Use the following code sample for converting object to JSON in ASP.NET MVC:

```
return this.Json(fileModel);
```

Comment: That was my problem! I was trying to over parse my response. I just needed to call the property! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

In your case, I think you're getting back the correct JSON, but your alert is looking at the wrong object. Try alert(obj.SomeProperty) rather than alert(e.obj). e.obj doesn't exist, which is likely why you're getting an "undefined" error. For example, alert(obj.fileModel.ProcessId); should work.

Comment: Any idea what was undefined? The function? Are you using something like Firebug or the Developers Tools in Chrome to help you out?